# TKinter all options for itemconfig()

Tags: python, tkinter

Every source of documentation I've been able to find for this say that by calling itemconfig without any arguments will return a list of possible attributes that can be edited. I tried to do this with the following code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()

print(w.itemconfig('bg'))
```

...And it only returned an empty dictionary (it throws an error when I put in zero arguments, and no other arguments I could think of have given me results, except for actually using the function as intented)

I find it rather silly that nobody has written down all of the attributes that itemconfig can use (or if they have, I can't find it); being able to actually retrieve attributes would be nice, but far more than that, I'd like a complete list to be written down, since I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: You have to supply at least one parameter to `.itemconfig()`, to specify a canvas item.  (In other words, you can't use it at all in your sample code, because you have no items.)  With no *additional* parameters, it shows you a dict of options that apply *to that particular item* - which differ depending on the type of item.  As for documentation, try https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm (the options are listed under the individual .create_XXXX() methods for each type of item).

Comment: Oh, if you were talking about options of *the Canvas itself*, that's `.config()`, not `.itemconfig()`.  That can be called with no parameters to get the full list of options.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks. I found that page before, but I wasn't able to figure out how to go from the itemconfig functions to the things it could actually edit.